# how to control an rgb node's color through a custom property

Tags: shaders, drivers

I have a couple of objects that are procedurally textured and colored. I want to make versions of it, and adjust the base color (defined by a rgb node) on everyone of them in one step.

So, I know how to create a custom property with color as a property value, but I do not know how to epecify the parameters in the driver editor when in the rgb node to make it work (as you can tell, I'm new to drivers in blender).

[image: the custom property should control the rgb node's color output]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like any other custom property, but you have to set a different driver for each channel.

Expand the color wheel by clicking on the custom property color field, set it to R,G,B and right click on the first channel, choose *Copy as new driver*.

Then expand the RGB node color wheel by clicking on the color field, set it to R,G,B and right click in the first channel, choose *Paste driver*.

Now repeat that for the Green, Blue, and Alpha channel and the two colors will be synched.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right! I was trying to do it in one go with the whole color, but this way it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!